# Why is "Slater's Condition" Important?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, combinatorial-optimization

I was watching the following (amazing) lecture on Mixed Integer Optimization (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xEQaDiAHDWk) and came across this slide that mentions **Slater's Condition**:

[image]

This was the first time I have heard about **Slater's Condition** and I was interested in learning more about this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmY3LUL6GkY):

[image]

Based on what I saw, this is what I understood:

- For a Convex Optimization Problem, if a solution "x" exists within the Feasible Region of this problem : Then this Optimization Problem has "strong duality"
- Since Mixed Integer Optimization Problems are always Non-Convex (since sets of integers are always non-convex), Slater's Condition does not hold.
- Since Slater's Condition does not hold, there is no Strong Duality.
- The above factors result in Combinatorial Optimization Problems being more difficult than Continuous Optimization Problems.

**Now, I am trying to understand the logic of the above points:**

- Why is it important that a solution to a Non-Convex Optimization Problem exists within the interior region or not? Are there any benefits for solutions that exist within the interior region compared to solutions that do not exist in the interior region?
- Why is it important to determine whether an Optimization Problem has Strong Duality or not?
- Why does the Feasible Set have no interior in a Combinatorial Optimization Problem? Do Combinatorial Optimization Problems have interior regions at all?
- Why don't Slater's Conditions hold if the Feasible Set has no interior? (i.e. Why don't Slater's Conditions hold for Combinatorial Optimization Problems?)
- Why does the absence of Strong Duality result in an Optimization Problem being more difficult?

**Can someone please help me understand the logic behind these facts? Currently I am just accepting them without really understanding why.**

Comment: This seems to ask a lot of questions.  See [ask]. Perhaps you could edit this into a single focused question?   (you can always ask more questions)

Comment: @ secretagentman: thank you for your reply! I thought of asking separate questions, but i thought since all of them are related to each other - it might be better to keep them in one place?

Comment: No worries.  Just trying to be helpful.   I'm no authority.  The OR.SE community may disagree with me, but I would recommend breaking these into more focused questions and just linking the separate posts.

Answer (score 4):

Slater’s condition is a type of constraint qualification (see [https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) for more details). These conditions are important for continuous problems and are independent from convexity.
If your optimization problem does not satisfy constraint qualification, the (local and global) optimal points do not necessarily have to be KKT points, in other words, you cannot use gradient information to look for the optimal solution (solvers look for KKT points using first and second derivatives) and you will have numerical trouble with solvers. For a simple example where this happens see: http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2014/07/4456.pdf (page 5).
A lack of  constraint qualification can be interpreted as a disconnect between the algebraic description of a feasible region and its geometric nature, this tends to happen when the problem is ill formulated.
A lack of constraint qualification is not what usually makes integer programming hard, non-convexity is responsible for that. In other words, the continuous relaxation of an integer program can satisfy slater’s condition but it can still be hard to find the globally optimal solution.